# Finding item(s) in python list where it is not grouped with similar values

Tags: python

I'm trying get a list (using Python) of indexes for items in a list that are not grouped with similar values.

For example, given the list `[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]` items at index 4,5,6,7 are errors because they're not grouped with the the first set of similar values. The first time an item or similar groups of items is seen in a list is considered the correct position, so order isn't really important. Ideally, I'd be returned a list of indexes like `[4,5,6,7]`

Comment: What do you mean by they are not grouped? The first four values are repeated twice.

Comment: And if the first time is correct why would you want the last four positions in the list returned?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if this works for you?

```
input_list=[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]
dict1={} #dictionary to store the values
return_list=[]

for i,v in enumerate(input_list):
    x=dict1.get(v)
    if(x!=None and x!=i-1):
        return_list.append(i)
    else:
        dict1[v]=i
print(return_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_incorrect_indecies(numbers):
    from itertools import groupby
    seen_keys = set()
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda tpl: tpl[1]):
        if key in seen_keys:
            for element in group:
                yield element[0]
        else:
            seen_keys.add(key)

numbers = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
print(list(get_incorrect_indecies(numbers)))
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```py
def checkgrouped(List: list) -> list:
    usedvalues = [] # stored the values already used
    badindexes = [] # stores the indexes of invalid items
    for i in range(len(List)): # Iterating over the range instead of the list itself to make it easier to check adjacent items and get indexes
        if List[i] in usedvalues: # Check if item was already stored in used values
            badindexes.append(i) # Append index of item to bad indexes if item is invalid
        elif List[i] != List[i + 1]: # Check if item is not different to the next item
            usedvalues.append(List[i]) # Append item to the list of used values
    return badindexes
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how:**

```
def check(lst):
    d = []
    for i,v in enumerate(lst):
        if v not in d or d[-1] == v:
            d.append(v)
        else:
            return [q for q in range(i,len(lst))]
print(check([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]))
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```